# Sorting SharePoint list item attachments alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Folks, i have items in my SharePoint 2010 list that have attachments. Is there any OOTB option to sort alphabetically these attachments? Or any custom workaround to to do? i have tried many options i.e using JS/Jquery script but no luck. Any guess?

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below article solved out my problem.

http://like2know.blogspot.com/2014/09/sorting-sharepoint-list-item.html